# Using parseint with jquery to find other values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several form fields that end in an integer value.  I want to find that integer and use it to find the values of other form fields.  Right now, when using the integer to create a jQuery selector, the selector results in `undefined` when trying to capture the value.

Form code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="checkbox" name="fee_hidden8" value="8" id="fee_hidden8" class="btoggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-close'></i> Hidden" data-off="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-open'></i> Visible" data-onstyle="danger" data-offstyle="success" data-size="small" >
     <br><span class="bg-warning">Waiting for Input</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="account_edit.cfm?fc=8&yr=2016&tab=1"><h4>New Leagues</h4></a><br />Season: 2016</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" id="fee_open_date8" name="fee_open_date8" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" id="fee_close_date8" name="fee_close_date8" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value=""></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="checkbox" name="fee_hidden7" value="7" id="fee_hidden7" class="btoggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-close'></i> Hidden" data-off="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-open'></i> Visible" data-onstyle="danger" data-offstyle="success" data-size="small" >
     <br><span class="bg-warning">Waiting for Input</span></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="account_edit.cfm?fc=7&yr=2016&tab=1"><h4>New Camps</h4></a><br />Season: 2016</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" id="fee_open_date7" name="fee_open_date7" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value=""></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="text" id="fee_close_date7" name="fee_close_date7" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value=""></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.btoggle').change(function() {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id").match(/(\d+)$/)[0], 10)
        var id = id.toString();

        if($("fee_hidden" + id).prop('checked'))
        {var st = 'Yes'}
        else
        {var st = 'No'};

        var fx = $("fee_hidden" + id).val();
        var od = $("fee_open_date" + id).val(); 
        var cd = $("fee_close_date" + id).val(); 
        alert(st + " " + id + " " + fx + " " + od + " " + cd);

        $.post("tsafunctions.cfc", {
            method: 'visiblehidden',
            fc: fx,
            status: st,
            od: od,
            cd: cd
            });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```js
  $(function() {
$('.btoggle').change(function() {
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr("id").match(/(\d+)$/)[0], 10);

    var st = $("#fee_hidden" + id).prop('checked') ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    var fx = $("#fee_hidden" + id).val();
    var od = $("#fee_open_date" + id).val();
    var cd = $("#fee_close_date" + id).val();

    console.log("st: ", st, " id: ", id, " fx: ", fx, " od: ", od, " cd: ", cd);

/**
    $.post("tsafunctions.cfc", {
        method: 'visiblehidden',
        fc: fx,
        status: st,
        od: od,
        cd: cd
        });
**/
})
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2"><input type="checkbox" name="fee_hidden8" value="8" id="fee_hidden8" class="btoggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-close'></i> Hidden" data-off="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-open'></i> Visible" data-onstyle="danger" data-offstyle="success" data-size="small" >
        <br>
        <span class="bg-warning">Waiting for Input</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="account_edit.cfm?fc=8&yr=2016&tab=1"><h4>New Leagues</h4></a>
        <br />Season: 2016
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" id="fee_open_date8" name="fee_open_date8" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" id="fee_close_date8" name="fee_close_date8" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="checkbox" name="fee_hidden7" value="7" id="fee_hidden7" class="btoggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-close'></i> Hidden" data-off="<i class='glyphicons glyphicons-eye-open'></i> Visible" data-onstyle="danger" data-offstyle="success" data-size="small" >
        <br>
        <span class="bg-warning">Waiting for Input</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="account_edit.cfm?fc=7&yr=2016&tab=1"><h4>New Camps</h4></a>
        <br />Season: 2016
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" id="fee_open_date7" name="fee_open_date7" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input type="text" id="fee_close_date7" name="fee_close_date7" class="pickdate btoggle form-control" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Click the `Run code snippet` button to test it out.  You can click the `Full page` button to see it full page and make it easier to see what's going on.  The console messages will be logged at the bottom of the screen to show that all of the values are properly retrieved.

The changes are:

- removed the redundant `id` variable
- added '#' for jQuery selectors to find the elements by id

There wasn't really much wrong, other than those two items, and the redundant `id` variable was likely not actually an issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew it was close.  Appreciate it.